# Canvas Drawing Effect

Tags: html, html5-canvas

Im starting on some simple-to-complex canvas scripting. I want to draw a circle. That's easy. The problem is the circle is drawn right away. What if I wanted the circle to slowly grow (lets say from a vertical line, to a semi circle, to a half circle, to a full circle)  Is there any way in canvas to do this (natively) or do I need to make a function that builds and deletes several circles (quickly) to simulate the effect?

If the latter is true, is there any sort of performance hits I should be looking out for?

Thank you!

Comment: Some confusion in your question. A semi circle is a half circle. Drawing a seies of circles wil not produce the effect of a circle growing from a straight line.

Comment: Sorry, I meant quarter circle. So line to quarter circle, to semi circle, to 3/4 circle, to full circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any form of animation using canvas requires the canvas to be cleared  and the next drawing  in the sequence to be made. The Mozilla  Development Network has a good tutorial on canvas and canvas animations.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [animate.js](https://github.com/gopi1410/AnimateJs) library. Its is exactly what you need. Usage is same as jQueryUI.

What you need can be done by the following piece of code:

```
canvas_element.animateCircle(x,y,r);
```

There are other optional parameters like `animateCircle(x,y,r,{'lineWidth':5, 'lineColour':'red', 'stop': function() {alert('completed');}})` & some other functions. Check the Readme file for details.

Comment: very good library gopi! only one thing, if it is possible... Canvas bezierCurveTo() Method to animate. i think, Start Point(moveto Method) parameter should be also included to your new function 'animateBezier'..?

Comment: @Sergej sure, I would love to do that when I get time. & you are always welcome to send pull requests at github https://github.com/gopi1410/AnimateJs